# Sharing folder and files (like Utilities.swift files) between targets [Xcode 11]

Tags: xcode

**Hello everyone!**
In my project I have two targets (please ignore the first one, I don't know what it is):
[image]

One target for iOS, and the other one for Apple Watch.
As you can see on the next image, I have a folder that is currency in the Apple Watch target (I am talking about the selected folder):

[image: My Project Navigatior.]

**And I want that the files, classes, and images (like Utilities.swift) in this folder will be accessible from both Apple Watch target and iOS target.**
 I'm currency using the latest Xcode version: Version 11.5 (11E608c).
How do I do that?
- Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer by myself.

I needed to go to the side menu and then select the targets I wanted, just like that:
[image]

Or when copying new files to the project:

[image]
And then I selected both target, and it worked.